# Como consumir um WebService "asmx" através do Ajax do Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, web-service

Criei um botão que chama o método buscarEmpresa que por sua vez é feita uma requisição `Ajax` para consumir um Web Service `Asxm`.

*Porque o `Ajax` não consome o Web Service?*

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPesquisar" runat="server" 
    Text="PesquisarEmpresa" OnClientClick="buscarEmpresa();"/>
```

*A função Ajax Jquery*

```
    function buscarEmpresa() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../webService/Ajax.asmx/GetEmpresa",
            data: "{'cnpj':'" + $("#inputCnpjEmpresa").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Cnpj);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Erro");
            }
        });

    }
```

*Meu Asmx.cs*

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Ajax : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public Ajax () {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static Empresa GetEmpresa(string cnpj)
    {
        return EmpresaControler.RetornaEmpresa(cnpj); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De tanto pesquisar e pelas dicas do @TiagoSilva, descobri que a anotação

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Estava comentada, era por isso que o script não consumiu o webService.