# WebService em C# com erro 404

Tags: c#, .net, web-service

Estou fazendo manutenção em um projeto C#, que tem WebServices. 
Criei um novo serviço e executei o programa, ele funciona conforme imagens abaixo, porém ao chamar o método dá erro 404.

Isto é um comportamento normal?

#### Código

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ServicosMegasul
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

#### Imagens

[image: Inicio do debug do projeto]
[image: Chamada do serviço]
[image: Erro ao chamar o serviço]

Comment: Qual a sua versão do IIS?

Comment: @jbueno Estou debugando ele pelo Visual Studio 2013. Deixar ver aqui.

Comment: @jbueno 7.5 IIS Express

Comment: Você usa Webservice ASMX? Tenho está pergunta no Stack: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34145/como-consumir-um-webservice-asmx-atrav%C3%A9s-do-ajax-do-jquery/34148#34148

Comment: @Marconi estou usando asmx. Porém continua o mesmo problema. Estou tentando descobrir como debugar.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que parece, isto é um problema meio comum quando se usa o IIS 7.5.

Segundo [esta resposta no StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891483/4190610), você deve adicionar isso no `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" name="asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você usa MVC na pasta app_start no registrador de rotas você pode ignorar a rota para seu web service, funcionou para mim.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```